# localhost to domain name.. Accessing the contents inside the 'resource' directory(laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I changed 'locahost' to 'abcd.com' domain name and its pointing to 'public' directory of the laravel application and working perfectly , but when try to access the '/admin' folder inside the 'resource/view' directory ,getting an error 'NotFoundHttpException' .How to fix that not found exception ? 
Any help would be appreciated ..
Thanks.

Comment: Main question is __why__ you need to access this folder from web?

Comment: I need an admin panel section for the application..

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access folder. I don't see why would you do it but this is why are are getting error. When accessing `/admin` Laravel thinks that you are trying to access `/admin` get route from your `web.php` and it's not there. That is the reason for `NotFoundHttpException`

If you want to handle that request anyway, in your `web.php` add this

```
Route::get('/admin','Controller@Method');
```

Comment: Thanks, your right . I was trying to get the route not defined .. i created it as name space in RouteServiceProvider, now its working.. thanks

Comment: @ARUNMadathil Glad that my answer helped you. If your problem is resolved It'd be cool if you could chose my answer for this question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have `index.blade.php` inside resourse/view directory you should use like this in web.php or in in controller

```
    view("admin.index");
```